# Printing table with div to create delete section

Tags: php, html-table

The code I am posting below, iterates through a result set and prints elements (paths to images on database) so that images display in order. Only 3 images per row. I want to be able to have the same concept (i.e. 3 images or cells per row) but I want to have another div underneath it to have the word delete photo.

```
$n = 3;
echo "<table style='margin-right: 100px;'>";
echo "<tr>";
for($i=1; $i<=count($gallery);$i++){
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i-1];
    echo "<td><div id='gallery_pic'><img id='single_pic' src='". $temp->path . "' /></div></td>";
    if($i % $n ==0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo "</table>";
```

The idea is that owner of profile should be able to delete photo by clicking it. I will handle that I am just not sure how to handle printing the table with same order by adding another row per row with delete word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Add a new `div` right after `div#gallery_pic` and give it a width of 100%, this will force it to be below the image...

```
echo "<table style='margin-right: 100px;'>";
echo "<tr>";
for($i=1; $i<=count($gallery);$i++){
    $temp = array();
    $temp = $gallery[$i-1];
    echo "<td><div id='gallery_pic'><img id='single_pic' src='". $temp->path . "' /></div><div class='delete_wrap'><a href='?delete_id=" . {image_id} . " style='width:100%'>Delete</a></div></td>";
    if($i % $n ==0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo "</table>";
```